# How can I see the final version of a Qweb template in Odoo/Openerp

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Example:

I have a template which two custom modules modify. Because module 1 removes an element that module 2 depends on (it's in its Xpath) the module 2 cannot be installed.

How can I see the architecture of the template after modification by other modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the template under Settings->Technical->Reports->reports then search for your report